# Flutter switch widget not updating

Tags: flutter

I have created a stateless widget that has a Flutter switch widget I implement this widget in the parent and pass in the required parameters but it won't change value when I press the switch.

I thought it might have been due to the fact that the child widget wasn't stateful but that made no difference.

Here is a brief example of code from my two widget files

```
class SettingsButton extends StatelessWidget {
 final String text;
 final bool initalValue;
 final void Function(bool) onOffCallback;

 SettingsButton({
    this.text,
    this.initalValue = false,
    this.onOffCallback,
  });

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: SubHeading(text),
      ),
      Switch(
        onChanged: isOnOff ? onOffCallback : null,
        activeColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        value: initalValue,
      )
    ]);
```

```
class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
  bool test = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              SettingsButton(
                text: "Test",
                onOffCallback: (test) => setState(() {
                  print("Called");
                  test = !test;
                }),
                initalValue: test,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to test your code. Where does the `Screen` class come from?

Comment: Oh sorry its a custom helper class that returns a media query, I'll remove it.

Comment: No worries. Um... I'm unclear about the Subheading bit. I assume that's a wrapper around Text, but where does the `text` variable come from?

Comment: It is passed in I removed it I didn't think it was relevant sorry

Comment: No problem. I just added back in a `text` variable for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the test variable recieved in the callback, rather than that defined in the `_SettingsState` class. What you should have is this for the callback:

```dart
onOffCallback: (newTest) => setState(() {
  print("$newTest");
  test = newTest;
  // or (it shouldn't matter)
  test = !test;
  print("$test");
}),
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for the help I knew it would be something silly like that